# Are Facebook Graph items persistent?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am wondering if it is safe to cache Facebook graph items and not have to check if they have been changed.

For example, if I download and cache of photo with the ID 1234309932123, is it safe to assume that the image for that ID will always be the same?

I assume that a given Facebook object cannot change, it can only be deleted. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

It is wrong to assume that `photo` object will not change. Photo is not only image but associated data as well, at least some of properties for `photo` can be changed: title, description, people/pages tags.

One more thing that can be changed aside of photo details is access permissions. Platform policies states that you should only show data retrieved from Facebook to people who have permission to view it, so caching photo may became an issue.

Comment: I am not going to cache the title, description, tags, etc. I am mainly interested in caching the photos as they are very large transfers in comparison. So the question is not if the metadata can change, but if it is possible for the actual photo to change, which it does not sound like it.

Comment: If only data you'll be caching is the image file you should be ok. Actually you can cache it based on URL provided in `photo` object to be sure you only use cached version if URL is not changed.